# Cards that restrict untapping of creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have been looking for two cards that I played with the other day and I cannot find.
They are both artifacts.

1. *Creatures with power 4 or more don't untap.*
2. *Creatures with power 2 or more don't untap.*

That may be a simplified version of the text, but that's what the abilities do.

Comment: [magiccards.info](http://magiccards.info/search.html) has far better search functions that Gatherer (and is much more pleasant to look at). It is kept up to date. (It's even more up to date than Gatherer since it includes cards from sets being previewed.)  [A search for "don't untap" in the card (Oracle) text](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22don%27t+untap%22&v=card&s=cname). [A search for "don't untap" and power  in the card (Oracle) text](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22don%27t+untap%22+o%3Apower&v=card&s=cname).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Gatherer website is the official portal to the Oracle database, the final authority on cards and their wording. Gatherer has extensive search function. You can find it [here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx).**

In the Advanced search tab, you can set all kinds of search criteria and usually find exactly what you're looking for.

That being said, there are no cards that would match your exact description. The best match I could come up with is [Meekstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMeekstone%5d). You might have to play around with the search parameters to find the cards you're looking for.

Comment: You can, for example, search for all cards that prevent untapping by creatures of a certain strength with [this search query](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[%22creatures%20with%20power%22]+[%22don%27t%20untap%22]).

Comment: There is another one... I know there is, maybe it was a white enchantment... I can't quite remember.

Comment: [[crackdown]]  ..

Comment: Crackdown is a white Enchantment, and Marble Titan is a white creature. Both are returned by the query in placed in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is [Meekstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=true&multiverseid=31)

> Creatures with power 3 or greater don't untap during their
>   controllers' untap steps.

I'm not sure about the first one. It's either [Juntu Stakes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23223), its ability has a similar effect that is worded differently or it is not an artifact.

Comment: [Meekstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425811)'s text does neither of what the questioner asks. [Juntu Stakes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23223) cares about power, but otherwise is quite far from what is asked for. As Hackworth mentioned, there are no cards that do what's asked for.

Comment: Creatures with power x etc don't untap... that is exactly what they're asking for. I suspect that the numbers are incorrect or the actual effects are different than what are stated in the question.

Comment: I guess I'm reading it this way because they're asking for two very specific conditions, both of which are "power X or greater" - [Juntu Stakes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23223) just doesn't do that. It *is* the only artifact other than [Meekstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425811) that prevents creatures from untapping based on power, but it's still a long shot to assume that it'll be helpful, seeing as those two artifacts will probably never go in the same deck.